# ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener is only called on some devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-view, windowinsets

I'm trying to display my app [edge-to-edge](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge) but results are not even consistent across devices. `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` is called on Pixel 4a/5 but not on Pixel 3 XL and Essential PH-1, the app just draws behind the status bar when I try to set padding (with or without `android:fitsSystemWindow="true"`). I suspect it's because of the notch (edge-to-edge doesn't work on Pixel 3 XL and Essential PH-1). I'm also using `CoordinatorLayout`, `DrawerLayout`, etc, so there's the whole `fitsSystemWindow` thing. I can't seem to get it to work no matter what. Watched a couple of Chris Banes' presentations but I'm still clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this problem be related to Display Cutoffs? Pixel 4a/5 have cutoffs whereas Pixel 3 doesn't.

From class WindowInsets.java:482

```
* Returns the display cutout if there is one.
* Note: the display cutout will already be consumed during dispatch to *View.onApplyWindowInsets, unless the window has requested a WindowManager.LayoutParams.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode other than never or default.
* Returns:
* the display cutout or null if there is none
* See Also:
* DisplayCutout
public DisplayCutout getDisplayCutout() {
    return mDisplayCutout;
}
```

Comment: Very likely. This issue doesn't concern me anymore but in hindsight, that was probably what I would've checked.